# 403 forbidden error while trying to connect SQS from Java application using AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I am trying to access SQS queues from my Java application using AWS-SDK in the Prod environment as follows:

```
  @Profile("prod")
  @Bean
  public AmazonSQSAsyncClient getAmazonSQSClientProd() {
    return (AmazonSQSAsyncClient) AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.fromName(awsRegion))
        .withCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance())
        .build();
```

While running the application, I am getting following exception:

```
15:06:12.415 [task-57] ERROR c.s.t.m.s.producer.SqsDataPublisher - Received exception from sqs
com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: Access to the resource https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/123456/queue_1.fifo is denied. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 8901234)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2202)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2169)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2158)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeSendMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1757)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.sendMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1729)
    at com.salesforce.tm.messaging.sqs.producer.SqsDataPublisher.sendMessageAndWaitForResult(SqsDataPublisher.java:54)
    at com.salesforce.tm.messaging.sqs.producer.SqsDataPublisher.sendInternal(SqsDataPublisher.java:60)
    at com.salesforce.tm.messaging.sqs.producer.SqsDataPublisher.sendMessage(SqsDataPublisher.java:104)
    at com.salesforce.tm.messaging.sqs.producer.SqsDataPublisher.sendMessage(SqsDataPublisher.java:81)
    at com.salesforce.tm.messaging.sqs.producer.SqsDataPublisher.sendMessage(SqsDataPublisher.java:72)
    at com.salesforce.tm.auditlog.AuditLogInterceptorHelper.saveAndPublish(AuditLogInterceptorHelper.java:36)
    at com.salesforce.tm.auditlog.AuditLogInterceptorHelper$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1ef9aa98.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I am not getting any clue regarding how to fix this.

Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Comment: You have `AccessDenied`. By "pod env", you mean EKS on ec2 or fargate?

Comment: @Marcin By Prod env I mean EKS on EC2.

Comment: Have you setup your [roles for your service account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html)?

Comment: @Marcin Yes I have set up. Attached policy is as follows:

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: What about SQS permissions policy?

Comment: @Mercin The permission policy attached to SQS is as follows:

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2: 123456:queue_1.fifo/SQSDefaultPolicy"
}

Comment: I mean, in the service account role, have you added permissions to access your sqs?

Comment: @Marcin, attached policy to the account is:

 "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ], "Effect": "Allow", "Resource": "*" } ] } 

So it takes care of all AWS resources.

Comment: If you check [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-service-account-iam-policy-and-role.html), they provide example policy for S3 read only access. So in my view you need to have something similar but for sqs, unless I misunderstand your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using SQS Java API V1. Try using the SQS V2 API. AN example is here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/sqs/src/main/java/com/example/sqs/SendReceiveMessages.java